# Nested blockquotes in latex

Tags: markdown, csquotes, nesting

Within Markdown it is possible to use nested blockquotes, which looks like this:

> Dorothy followed her through many of the beautiful rooms in her castle.
>
> > The Witch bade her clean the pots and kettles and sweep the floor and keep the fire fed with wood.

Imagine your standard whatsapp conversation, where you can reply directly to a message, now imagine you can do that multiple times to create some thread where previous replies are nested inside. Like this:

> I forgot, I cannot.
>
> > I'm in for sports.
> >
> > > Anyone wants to play tonight?

What would be the equivalent tag to achieve this in latex?

I would prefer an "easy one-to-one" solution if there is any. I did find few similar topics, but none of those addressed the nesting part, only how to add background colour.

edit:

I have found something like this:

```
\begin{displayquote}There for I am happy.
\begin{displayquote}So we are happy.
\begin{displayquote}Everyone is happy.
\end{displayquote}
\end{displayquote}
\end{displayquote}
```

Which does indent everything nicely, but now would also like to add a bit of bgcolor to separate the specific blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe with the `tcolorbox` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Alice,colback=yellow!10!white]
I forgot, I cannot.
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Bob,colback=red!10!white]
I'm in for sports.
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Charlie,colback=blue!10!white]
Anyone wants to play tonight?
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

These boxes are highly customizable, see the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) for a full overview.

Comment: That is a lot more in the direction that I wanted to go already. Thanks.